# Drawing multiple fish at random locations

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to create a java project with an aquarium with up to eight fish at random locations.  The fish should only move when dragged with the mouse. We used images for the aquarium background and the fish.  I am at the point where I can create one fish at the center, and now need to draw multiple fish (up to eight) at random places.

This is from my assignment

> Now, we would like to add up to 8 fish to our fish tank and draw them
> at random positions of the window display. To generate these random
> positions, we are going to use the randGen static variable of type
> Random that we already defined outside of any method. First, make sure
> to create a Random object in the setup() method and assign its
> reference to the static variable randGen.
> (float)randGen.nextInt(processing.width) // generates a random
> x-position of type // float within the width of the display window
> (float)randGen.nextInt(processing.height) // generates a random
> y-position of type // float within the height of the display window To
> create a Fish at a given position of the display window, call the
> constructor of the class Fish which takes three input parameters
> Fish(PApplet, float, float). Then, you can store the reference of the
> created Fish object returned by the Fish constructor call into the
> position 0 of the array fishes. Next, you can add a for-loop to draw
> the Fish objects pointed by each of the non-null references in the
> fishes array by calling each Fish object’s draw() method
> appropriately. Having this done, you can now test your program with
> different numbers of fishes at random positions within the display
> window, and with a fishes array of different sizes. Before moving on
> to the next step, make fishes reference an array of length eight. Make
> all but the first of these references null, and make the first one a
> reference to a Fish object located at a random position of the
> screen."

this is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.File;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;
public class FishTank {
    private static PApplet processing; // PApplet object that represents the graphic
                                       // interface of the JunglePark application
    private static PImage backgroundImage;  // PImage object that represents the
                                            // background image
    private static Fish[] fishes;   // perfect size array storing the different fish present
                                    // in the fish tank.  These fish can be different species.
    private static Random randGen;  // generator of random numbers.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Utility.startApplication();  //starts the application
    }
    /**
     * Defines the initial environment properties of this application
     * @param processingOBJ a reference to the graphic display window of this application
     */
    public static void setup(PApplet processingOBJ) {   
        processing = processingOBJ;
        // load the image of the background
        backgroundImage = processing.loadImage("images/background.png");
        //Draw the background image at the center of the screen
        processing.image(backgroundImage,  processing.width / 2,  processing.height / 2);
        // width [resp.height]  System variable of the processing library that stores
        // the width [resp. height] of the display window.
        fishes = new Fish[8]; 
        fishes[0] = new Fish(processing, processing.width / 2, processing.height / 2);
        Random randGen = new Random();
        //float num = randGen.nextInt(processing.width); //generates a random x-position of type
                                         //float within the width of the display window.
        //float num1 = randGen.nextInt(processing.height);
    }
    
    /**
     * Draws and updates the application display window.
     * This callback method called in an infinite loop
     */
    public static void draw() {
        for (int i =0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
            if (fishes[i] != null) {
                fishes [i].draw(); // where i is the index of the created Fish in the fishes array
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Callback method called each time the user presses the mouse.
     */
    public static void mousePressed() {
        
        }
    
    /**
     * Callback method called each time the mouse is released
     */
    public static void mouseReleased() {
        
    }
    
    public static void keyPressed() {
        
    }
    /**
     * Checks if the mouse is over a specific Fish whose reference is provided
     * as input parameter
     * 
     * @param Fish reference to a specific fish
     * @return true if the mouse is over the specific Fish object (i.e. over 
     *           the image of the Fish), Fallse otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isMouseOver(Fish fish) {
        float X = fish.getPositionX();
        float Y = fish.getPositionY();
        if ((X - fish.getImage().width/2) < processing.mouseX && processing.mouseX < (X + fish.getImage().width/2) &&
        (Y - fish.getImage().height/2) < processing.mouseY && processing.mouseY < (Y + fish.getImage().height/2))
        {
            return true;  //If mouse is over the boundaries of fish returns true
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? "Here is my assignment, here is my code" is not a question. :(

Comment: Better try to specify what you need. Otherwise this question might get deleted if you don't improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You already have implemented most of what you needed to. You also succeeded in creating at least one fish at a hardcoded position (center). We can proceed from where you initialized the fish array.

After creating the fish array of length 8 we just need to fill it up with fishes at random positions.

To get random values your assigment states

> [...] First, make sure to create a Random object in the setup() method and assign its reference to the static variable randGen [...]

You kinda did that but you created a `local` variable instead of assining to the `static` one. So instead of `Random randGen = new Random();` you'll need to write `randGen = new Random();` as you did with the `fishes`.

For that a for loop is probably the smartest choice (as seen in the draw method) where we create fishes with the positions generated by the random object.

From your assignment

> [...] (float) randGen.nextInt(processing.width) // generates a random x-position of type float within the width of the display window (float) randGen.nextInt(processing.height) // generates a random y-position of type // float within the height of the display window [...]

```java
[...]

fishes = new Fish[8];
randGen = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
    float x = (float) randGen.nextInt(processing.width);
    float y = (float) randGen.nextInt(processing.height);
    fishes[i] = new Fish(processing, x, y);
}

[...]
```